# XNA - Farseer Physics 3.5 - Collision Detection Issues - No/Zero Gravity - Space Game

Tags: c#, xna, physics, physics-engine, farseer

So I'm working on a space game called Star Commander.

The progress was going beautifully until I decided I needed to implement some sort of physics. I'm mainly going to be needing Farseer Physics for collision detection.

Anyway, since it's a space game, when I am declaring my 'World' object:

```
private World world;
this.world = new World(Vector2.Zero);
```

I have no gravity. This causes a weird result. I can collide with objects, but once I stop colliding with them, that's it. I can no longer collide with them and will just go straight through them. However, with gravity:

```
private World world;
this.world = new World(new Vector2(0F, 1F));
```

Collision works beautifully.

I've tried looking around for help with Farseer, but a lot of the posts are dated and there are no real good sources for information and sadly, I'm pretty sure I'm not going to get the help I need here either.

The only thing I found whilst looking around was that with objects called "Geoms" I need to disable a property called "CollisionResponeEnabled" or something similar.

However the Geom object is no longer present in Farseer Physics 3 and has been totally replaced by Fixtures. Fixtures do not seem to have this property, however.

I can provide any source code that may help, but keep in mind I am still implementing the physics engine into my project and a lot of the code isn't final and kind of messy.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

After recording a short gif to demonstrate my issue, I found out that I can only collide with an object once, to collide with it again, I have to collide with a different object, but then cannot collide with that object until I collide with a different object.

Example:

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that your bodies might be "sleeping" after the collision. Have you tried setting `SleepingAllowed = false` on the bodies to see if this is the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much. ananthonline I set my player's body to SleepAllowed = false and it worked flawlessly. I appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: I will add this as an answer, please accept so people who come by later can find it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your bodies might be "sleeping" after the collision. Have you tried setting `SleepingAllowed = false` on the bodies to see if this is the problem?